# How can I know the number of Installs of my android APK?

Tags: java, android

I have distributed my app through posting the link from google drive where the users can download the .apk file.Now that I haven't published my app in google play how to know how many installs or how many people have installed my application.Is there a way I can increase the count variable in the server or something like that?

Comment: you can't, unless you planned for it when you developed it. do you include any tracking tool, or uniquely identify requests to a server, or anything like that? if not, you're out of luck.

Comment: "In the server" means what exactly? Does your app communicate with a server? If so, then put a network request in your app

Comment: No, it doesn't, not in distributed one.But, what if it does communicate?is there a way to keep track of installs?@cricket_007

Answer (score 2):

Unless you went through the App Store or integrated some third party analytics tool like [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/) you would need to have implemented this in the application with a request to a server with a unique identifier to keep track.

Comment: Thank you , I will check this out@carlpoole

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can increase the count variable in the server or something like that?

Well that seems a bit shady. You don't want to lie to people, do you?

When you release an app on the Play Store, Google will keep track of how many users download your app, and update it accordingly. So if people use your app, then your downloads (listed on the Play Store) will reflect that.

To see your current downloads, you should be able to find that information on the "Google Play Developer Console." (I would imagine; I currently don't have access to the dashboard myself.)

Comment: by count variable I mean, whenever an app gets installed the count variable must be incremented btw I haven't published in the store.

Comment: Then what @carolpoole said, you would have to have some server where you are getting requests from users who install the app. You could make a request that is only called when a user runs the app the first time, thus indicating an install.